# Registry Access via C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

To access the Registry I use the **Microsoft.Win32** and the classes **Registry** and **RegistryKey**. Are there other possibilities to access the registry via .NET?

Comment: You could P/Invoke the Win32 APIs. What are you looking for?

Comment: Why do you need OTHER possibilities?

Comment: You could use .reg files - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516

Answer (score 0):

The whole WINAPI is virtually available to you via Interop. But why would you need ***other*** means if .Net provides such a nice wrapper to you already ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try use Win API for registry access instead of using embedded .net classes

Answer (score 0):

You can add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a registration entries (.reg) file. This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516) explains it.